# IMGLYMainEditorViewController issue

Tags: ios, image, photo, editing

hey community I've installed the IMG.LY SDK into my project and I'm having trouble using it in my app. I want to pass an image through the SDK just to edit, I don't want to use the camera function to capture photos. I'm trying to edit images selected from the photo library. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong one button selects the picture from library the other edits it. When I hit the edit button nothing happens.

```
      @IBAction fun chooseImage(sender: AnyObject) {




    let image = UIImagePickerController()
    image.delegate = self
    image.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    image.allowsEditing = false

    self.presentViewController(image, animated: true, completion: nil)

}



        func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {

            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:nil)

            imageToPost.image = image



}




@IBAction func editPicture(sender: AnyObject) {





    func callEditorViewController(image: UIImage) {
        let editorViewController = IMGLYMainEditorViewController()
        editorViewController.highResolutionImage = image
        editorViewController.initialFilterType = .None
        editorViewController.initialFilterIntensity = 0.5
        editorViewController.completionBlock = editorCompletionBlock
    }


    func editorCompletionBlock(result: IMGLYEditorResult, image: UIImage?) {


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You never presented the view controller that you made in `callEditorViewController(_:)`. Add this to the end of that function:

```
presentViewController(editorViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```